# Linear Independence through Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Does anyone know how to prove the following statement?

> Consider a linear transformation $T:U \to V$. Prove that if the set  $ \{T(u_1), T(u_2), \ldots , T(u_n)\} $ is linearly independent in $V$, then $ \{u_1,\ldots , u_n\} $ is linearly independent in $U$.

I've alreadly found some explanations on the other way around, where ${u1, ... , un}$ are said independent. But those explanations assume $T$ to be invertible, and that is not something that is assumed here.

Comment: Have you thought about approaching this through [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)?

Comment: No, and i may have found a solution.
Is it right to say that if the set {t(u1) + t(u2) + .. + t(un)} is linearly independent ,then the kernel dimension is 0? Because then there is only the trivial solution that is equal to (0,0, ... , 0) and that would make the transformation injective.

Comment: No, because there may be some other $x\in U$ such that $T(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to show the equivalent statement:

> If $u_1,\ldots , u_n$ are linearly dependent in $U$, then $ T(u_1), T(u_2), \ldots , T(u_n)$ is linearly dependent in $V$.

By hypothesis, there are $a_1,\dotsc,a_n\in F$ (where $F$ is the field of the spaces $U,V$), not all zero, such that
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i u_i = 0.$$
Applying $T$ gives
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i T(u_i) &= \sum_{i=1}^n T(a_i u_i) \\
&= T(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i u_i) \\
&= T(0) \\
&= 0,
\end{align}$$
so the $T(u_i)$ are linearly dependent too.

Comment: Is this true for the linear independece case too? Or should i use Contraposition after proving this?

Comment: The highlighted statement IS the contrapositive. Instead of proving $p\to q$, you prove $\neg q\to \neg p$. The two statements are equivalent. You can also think of it as a proof by contradiction (suppose $p$, but $\neg q$; then $\neg p$; so $\neg p$ after all), only there's no need to assume $p$ at the outset.  In this case the contrapositive is easier to work with, because dependence is an existential statement: *there are* $a_i$ not all zero such that blah-blah.

Comment: What if the distinct $u_i$ maps to the same element? For example, though you know that $3u_1-3u_2+0u_3=0$, then you deduce that $3T(u_1)-3T(u_2)+0T(u_3)=0$, however, $T(u_1)$ and $T(u_2)$ can probably be the same! That is $(3-3)T(u_1)+T(u_3)=0$. Then you can't say that the vector $T(u_1)$ and $T(u_3)$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: @Eric If distinct $u_i$ map to the same element under $T$ then those images are linearly dependent and there's nothing to prove (the statement is true)